# Background Image - SharePoint 2013 - Recommended Size

Tags: 2013, image, image-display

I want to use a new image for the background to a new site in SharePoint 2013. Essentially I want a solid colour to replace the image that the 'Change the look' section puts in place.

I can produce the image easily enough in MS Paint but what I need to know is - what size should the image be in order to cover the entire screen?

Answer (score 1):

The exact size of the image does not matter. Every screen is different. But choosing the image for a background follow these rules I came up with:

- Choose an image with at least 1024x768 px in size.
- Try not to use background images in the first place, they rarely look good with SharePoint 2013 anyway.
- Choose an image with no people or faces, text, etc, because the image can be cut out depending on the window size.
- Patterned backgrounds work best since you don't care if something gets cutout and patterns don't produce too much noise.
- Make the image as light as possible. It should be almost white. You should probably choose of opacity that is no higher than 20% or even 5-10%. Otherwise it will produce too much noise and will interfere with the text on the screen.